# Ends of Array behave weirdly on ends of a NURBS curve

Tags: modifiers, curve-modifier

I don't understand what is really happening so I don't know how to fix it or really how to describe it.
I checked the basic stuff like origin point, normals, offsets, directions and some other basic stuff I could think off.
[image: Overview]

The same thing happens on the other side but I "fixed it" with offsetting arrayed object by a random number. Didn't entirely fix the issue but made it bearable. Here it didn't work.

[image: Modifiers]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm redoing these curves manually and so far it seems to have helped but if anyone has any idea what might have caused that I would be thankful

Comment: It is a bit hard to understand what we are looking at ... how should it look like. But since you use Nurbs type and array ends with last point there are probably two points.

Comment: Could you maybe share the blend file with the problem over blend exchange?  https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: first comment was right. End verticies of a curve were doubled somehow.